# Can I say not else than in this context?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Context when I see someone important, I say: Wow, I saw "no else" than him.:

> I saw yesterday not else than Trump!

Is it correct to use "not else than" as that?

Should I have said: "Not different than Trump" ?

Comment: Neither statement makes sense. It's hard to know what you are trying to say.

Comment: @RonaldSole when I see someone important, I say: Wow, I saw "no else" than him. did you get me?

Comment: Google Books Ngram Viewer indicates that the phrase **no-one else than** is occasionally used although **no-one other than** is far more popular. **Not else than** and **not different than** are both wrong after **I saw....** https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no-one+else+than%2Cno-one+other+than&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20-%20one%20else%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20-%20one%20other%20than%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @RonaldSole Round our way (UK) it's "none other than", and it is an idiom so common it's a cliche.

Comment: @PrimeMover Round my way too - as an abbreviated form of **no-one other than**. I should have included it in my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you may be aiming for is:

"Yesterday I saw none other than Trump."

It's idiomatic to express surprise at meeting someone so unique. "Yesterday, good gracious me! I saw Trump!"